# Convert list into multiple tuples in scala

Tags: scala

I have the following tuples: `(1,"3idiots",List("Action","Adventure","Horror")` Which I need to convert into a list in the following format:

```
List(
  (1,"3idiots","Action"),
  (1,"3idiots","Adventure")
)
```

Comment: please add the code ?

Comment: So what have you tried? Where are you stuck? What functions do you think would be useful? You have read the documentation, right? (Hint: `flatMap`)

Comment: and what about "Horror"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have more than one tuple like this:

```
val tuples = List(
    (1, "3idiots", List("Action", "Adventure", "Horror")),
    (2, "foobar", List("Foo", "Bar"))
)
```

and you want result like this:

```
List(
    (1, "3idiots", "Action"),
    (1, "3idiots" , "Adventure"),
    (1, "3idiots", "Horror"),
    (2, "foobar", "Foo"),
    (2, "foobar", "Bar")
)
```

the solution for you would be to use a `flatMap`, which can convert a list of lists to a single list:

```
tuples.flatMap(t =>
    t._3.map(s =>
        (t._1, t._2, s)
    )
)
```

or shorter: `tuples.flatMap(t => t._3.map((t._1, t._2, _)))`

Answer (score 6):

To add to previous answers, you can also use **for-comprehension** in this case; it might make things clearer IMHO:

```
for(
     (a,b,l) <- ts; 
     s <- l
) yield (a,b,s)
```

So if you have:

```
val ts = List(
  ("a","1", List("foo","bar","baz")),
  ("b","2", List("foo1","bar1","baz1"))
)
```

You will get:

```
List(
      (a,1,foo), 
      (a,1,bar), 
      (a,1,baz),
      (b,2,foo1), 
      (b,2,bar1), 
      (b,2,baz1)
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
val input = (1,"3idiots",List("Action","Adventure","Horror"))    
val result = input._3.map(x => (input._1,input._2,x))
// gives List((1,3idiots,Action), (1,3idiots,Adventure), (1,3idiots,Horror))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
val question = (1,"3idiots",List("Action","Adventure","Horror"))
val result = question._3.map(x=> (question._1 , question._2 ,x))
```